# Determining template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following situation in my legacy code base

```
class Legacy
{
public:
    void LegacyFn(bool b)
    {
        if (b)
        {
            // some code
            Legacy l;
            l.LegacyFn(!b);
        }
        else
        {
            // some code
        }
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I don't have the luxury to make Legacy a template class and neither do I have the luxury of making LegacyFn as template function or pass any parameters (including default).

My Goal is to alter LegacyFn function to use a strategy object. Therefore, I provided a LegacyFn template function that instantiates the appropriate strategy object and configures inside Legacy class. However my problem is in determining the actual concrete type of Strategy object configured by the templated LegacyFn while calling the original LegacyFn

```
#include <memory>

// new implementation
class IStrategy
{
public:
    virtual void g() = 0;
};

// new implementation
class ConcreteStrategy : public IStrategy
{
public:
    void g() override
    {

    }
};

class Legacy
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void LegacyFn(bool b)
    {
        m_actionImpl.reset(new typename
            std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IStrategy, T>::value,
            T>::type());
        return LegacyFn(b);
    }

    void LegacyFn(bool b)
    {
        if (b)
        {
            // some code
            Legacy l;
            l.LegacyFn<??>(false);        <--- **My problem is here**
                                                  <--- I want it to be ConcreteStrategy
                                                  <--- object, as the same class was
                                                  <--- used by the calling function template
                                                  <--- as the strategy object
        }
        else
        {
            m_actionImpl->g();
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<IStrategy> m_actionImpl;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Legacy l;
    l.LegacyFn<ConcreteStrategy>(true);
}
```

Comment: Side remark: That `enable_if` looks like it wants to be a `static_assert`.

Comment: You could add a virtual function to `m_actionImpl`, to allow something like `m_actionImpl->CallLegacyFn(l);`

Comment: @dyp - agree. will explore the point on static_assert

Comment: Perhaps you could have `LegacyFn<T>` capture a factory: `function<IStrategy*()> m_factory; m_factory = []{return new T;}`. Now you can make new copies of the strategy at will with `m_factory()`. Finally, add a `SetFactory` or `SetStrategy` method to `Legacy`, so that you could pass along either the factory, or a new strategy it manufactures.

Comment: I think I saw this question on TV in a show called "When design patterns attack!" @IgorTandetnik, please no! That factory should return a smart pointer, otherwise the entire codebase will be infected with a smell that will never go away.